# Как добавить к Pandas DataFrame новый столбец, полученный на основе его собственных значений?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame, для каждого столбца которого нужно рассчитать сглаженные средние и добавить столбец с новыми значениями к исходному DataFrame-у. Например, на входе:

```
    a   b   c
0   0   1   2
1   4   5   6
2   8   9   10
3   12  13  14

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4), columns=list('abcd'))
yArray = df['d']
df = df.drop('d', axis=1)
globalYMean = sum(yArray) / len(yArray)
meanAlpha = 0.7
print(df)

from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
for column in df.columns:
    le.fit(df[column])
    df[column] = le.transform(df[column])
    print(str(column) + "    " + str(len(df[column].value_counts())))

newX = df.copy()
print(newX)
for column in df.columns:
    newColumn = column + 'sm'
    counts = df[column].value_counts()
    innerLength = len(df[column].value_counts())
    j = 0
    smoothedDFCollection = pd.DataFrame(columns=[newColumn])
    print(smoothedDFCollection)
    for value, _ in df[column].value_counts().iteritems():
        valueIndex = df[df[column] == value].index
        smoothedMeanValues = (sum(valueIndex) / len(valueIndex) * len(df) + globalYMean * meanAlpha) / (
        len(df) + meanAlpha)
        smoothedDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=[newColumn], index=valueIndex, data=smoothedMeanValues)
        smoothedDFCollection = pd.concat([smoothedDFCollection, smoothedDF], axis=1)
        print("DF:")
        print(smoothedDF)

        j += 1
    print("Smoothed:")
    print(smoothedDFCollection)
    newX = pd.concat([newX, smoothedDFCollection])
    print(newX)

    print(i * 100 / length)
    i += 1
    print("Sum: " + str(shapeSum))
    print(newX)
    print()
```

На данный момент, на выходе следующее:

```
DF:
        asm
3  3.893617
DF:
        asm
2  3.042553
DF:
        asm
1  2.191489
DF:
        asm
0  1.340426
Smoothed:
   asm       asm       asm       asm       asm
0  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  1.340426
1  NaN       NaN       NaN  2.191489       NaN
2  NaN       NaN  3.042553       NaN       NaN
3  NaN  3.893617       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Понятно, что строка

```
        newX = pd.concat([newX,smoothedDFCollection])
```

падает с ошибкой

```
ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned
```

Нужно получить новый столбец значений, а не разреженный DataFrame. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём проблема.

Comment: Спасибо, Вы правы) Какой же стыд :|

Comment: Я бы этот вопрос не удалял, а переформулировал и добавил маленький входной "data set" и выходной "data set". Текущая реализация "цикл в цикле" - это классический "anti pattern" при использовании Pandas

Comment: @MaxU, буду рад научиться принятому в Python решению. Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на пример. А для чего добавлять датафреймы?

Comment: @KOHTPOJIEP, сила Pandas в векторизированном подходе. Если вы добавите пример входных (в CSV формате) и выходных данных, то я постараюсь набросать рабочий вариант кода... В качестве входного DataFrame можно взять: `df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3), columns=list('abc'))`

Comment: @KOHTPOJIEP, примеры фреймов помогут понять логику вашего "сглаженного среднего" и позволят проверить код на правильность. [Здесь описано как правильно задавать вопросы по Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо, что тратите время. Я пытаюсь запилить рабочий пример.

Comment: @MaxU, я оформил пример. Гляньте, пожалуйста. Заодно и проблема стала более понятной мне самому.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62139/discussion-between-kohtpojiep-and-maxu).

Comment: Я так и не понял как вы считаете `smoothedMeanValues`...

Comment: @MaxU, считается среднее значение для каждого класса LabelEncoder.  Т.е. среднее той части массива Y, индексы которой совпадают, например, с индексами класса 0. Вопрос уже решён. Возможно, конечный результат лучше объяснит, о чём я спрашивал. Но увидеть коррекцию вложенных циклов тоже будет полезно:)

Answer (score 1):

Путём некоторого изменения логики добавления, можно добиться нужного эффекта. Чтобы не итерироваться по уже созданным столбцам, сохраним их в отдельную переменную. 
Затем, с помощью

```
df[newColumn] = None
```

создадим новый столбец. А строкой

```
df.loc[valueIndex, newColumn] = smoothedMeanValues
```

заполним его:

```
columns = df.columns
print("Columns:")
print(columns)
for column in columns:
            newColumn = column + 'sm'
            df[newColumn] = None
            col_df = df[column]
            innerLength = len(df[column].value_counts())
            j = 0
            smoothedDFCollection = pd.DataFrame(columns=[newColumn])
            for value,_ in df[column].value_counts().iteritems():
                valueIndex = col_df == value
                smoothedMeanValues = (yArray[valueIndex].mean()*len(col_df) + globalYMean*meanAlpha)/(len(col_df) + meanAlpha)
                df.loc[valueIndex, newColumn] = smoothedMeanValues
print(df)
```

Результат:

```
    a   b   c   asm     bsm     csm
0   0   0   0   1.34043 1.34043 1.34043
1   1   1   1   2.19149 2.19149 2.19149
2   2   2   2   3.04255 3.04255 3.04255
3   3   3   3   3.89362 3.89362 3.89362
```